# Monomorphism if and only if injective

Tags: functions, solution-verification

The definition of monomorphism in Aluffi's book is:

> A function $f: A \to B$ is a monomorphism if for all sets $Z$ and all functions $\alpha' \alpha'' : Z \to A$, $f \circ \alpha' = f \circ \alpha'' \implies \alpha' = \alpha''$.

The result I'm trying to follow the proof of is: $f$ is injective if and only if it is a monomorphism.

He proved earlier that if $A \neq \emptyset$, $f: A \to B$ is injective if and only if it has a left inverse. We need the assumption that $A$ is nonempty because for any $B \neq \emptyset$, $f: \emptyset \to B$ is vacuously injective, but there are no functions $B \to \emptyset$ and hence no left inverses.

In this proof, Aluffi makes no such assumptions about $A$ being nonempty, but immediately invokes the result that if $f$ is injective, it has a left inverse, which is true only if $A$ is nonempty. Whether I need the assumption boils down to how I should read this definition.

The first interpretation is: the result needn't be true for ALL sets $Z$, but only all sets $Z$ for which there is a function $\alpha: Z \to A$. If $A = \emptyset$, $f: A \to B$ is vacuously injective for any $B$, but the *only* function $\alpha: Z \to A$ I can define is the empty function where $Z = \emptyset$. So, vacuously, $\alpha' = \alpha''$: both are the empty function.

The other interpretation is that this has to be true for *any* set $Z$, including nonempty sets $Z$, so the fact that I can't define a function $f: Z \to \emptyset$ is a problem and requires that $A \neq \emptyset$ be built into the assumptions of the problem.

Which interpretation is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of monomorphism is *for any set*, including the empty set. But if there is no function $Z \rightarrow A$, then the condition

$$\forall\alpha,\alpha’:Z\rightarrow A:f\alpha = f\alpha‘\implies \alpha=\alpha‘$$

is trivially satisfied, hence $Z$ does not matter when determining monomorphicity. This is to say both interpretations are equivalent. In fact this explains, why the unique morphism $\emptyset\rightarrow X$ for some set $X$ is a monomorphism (which needn’t be true in an arbitrary category), since there are no morphisms from an inhabited set into $\emptyset$…